# How do I add an attribute to AsyncMock?

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio, pytest-asyncio

Code:

```
class SomeClass(BaseClass):
    async def async_method(arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
        await self.foo.bar(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2).baz(**kwargs)
```

One of the tests used:

```
@pytest.fixture
def same_class():
    return SameClass()


async def test_async_method(some_class: SomeClass):
    arg1_mock = 1
    arg2_mock = 2
    some_class.foo.bar = AsyncMock()
    some_class.foo.bar.baz = AsyncMock()
    
    await some_class.async_method(arg1=arg1_mock, arg2=arg2_moc)
    
    some_class.foo.bar.assert_called_once()
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'baz'
```

How to add an asynchronous attribute method to AsyncMock? Any help

Answer (score 2):

From [the `AsyncMock` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock)

> The `AsyncMock` object will behave so the object is recognized as an async function, and the result of a call is an awaitable.

In your code, `bar` is the async function that returns an awaitable. To make the awaitable return something with a `baz` attribute, set it on the return value instead.

```
some_class.foo.bar = AsyncMock()
some_class.foo.bar.return_value.baz = AsyncMock()
```

Comment: This returns the same error